# execute a bash command on a list of files on stdin and redirect the stdout to related files

Tags: bash, shell

I want to execute a bash script on a list of text files (using a `for` loop, I guess), redirecting stdout to a file with the same path as the text file from stdin plus an extension (for example .txt or .sam, or just add a ~ to the end of the stdin path to make it different).

Comment: I got lost, could you put an example of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @tripleee you did observe that this question was asked in 2012, and the one you claim it duplicates was asked in 2013, right? I mean, you *did* think to check the dates so that you don't cause an anachronism and destroy the space0time continuum.

Comment: @CharlieMartin Thanks for asking.  I didn't notice, no; but the age of a question is a secondary concern.  A question with a better exposition of the problem and/or multiple good answers is a better choice as the "duplicate of" target, regardless of the age of the questions; and when both questions are old, in particular, it is not unusual for the newer of the two to be more canonical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, assuming the list isn't too long, you can start with

```
  for i in `cat list`
  do
      # do stuff here
  done
```

If the list is long enough to risk a too-long command line, there's a while variant

```
  cat list | while read i
  do
       # do stuff here
  done
```

you can construct the file name using basename(1) to get rid of the old extension suffix; for say .txt to .bak use

```
  `basename .txt ${i}`.bak
```

you can get the path part using dirname(1)

Since macros are expanded early, you can simply construct the command line in variables and expand them.  Where op and np are your path names

```
   command < $op > $np
```

There's a lovely on-line book, the [bash Advanced Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) that covers this and more.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and obviously, the `cat` is [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: See also http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/tutoriallist#rv_abs for some (very mild) caveats regarding the ABS guide.  The consensus is that it should not be your first-stop shop for scripting advice.  The linked page recommends some other tutorials (scroll back up a couple of notches).

Comment: Maybe follow up on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298192/disagreement-on-duplication-action